# Добавить товары в заказ до оплаты

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте! Пишу в первый раз сайт интернет-магазина и столкнулся с проблемой: как добавить товары в заказы, до оплаты заказа? т.е. есть таблица, например, `Orders`, в которую товары попадают после оплаты, но, как хранить эти товары до оплаты? Прочитал что нужно создать промежуточную таблицу с ID товаров и заказов, но не совсем понятно как добавлять туда значения ID заказа, если я еще в таблицу `Orders` ничего не вносил? В общем какая-то каша в голове, покажите какой-то пример или ресурс, где об этом можно почитать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть корзина (если я вас правильно понял), но её логика может быть разной ...

Я делаю так:

- для анонимного пользователя помещаю текущие товары в корзине в сессию;
- для зарегистрированного — в таблицу `users` в поле `products_in_cart`.

При оформлении заказа, в зависимости от того, кто его оформлял: аноним или зарегистрированный пользователь; переношу товары либо из сессии, либо из таблицы `users` соответственно в таблицу `orders` и ставлю в поле `is_paid` значение `0`, которое говорит о том, что заказ не оплачен; после оплаты меняю значение поля `is_paid` в таблице `orders` на `1`, которое говорит о том, что заказ оплачен ...

Answer (score 1):

Промежуточную таблицу создавать нет необходимости. Достаточно ввести поле статуса в таблицу «заказы» и поле «текущий формируемый заказ» в таблицу «пользователи».

Тогда при желании пользователя начать формирование заказа создаём новую запись в таблице «заказы» (значение статуса по умолчанию должно обозначать «формируется») и заносим идентификатор созданной записи в поле «текущий формируемый заказ». При оплате же этого заказа обнуляем поле «текущий формируемый заказ» и переводим статус заказа во «в оплате».

Comment: Немного не так я себе представлял этот процесс. А если оплата не поступит, вручную удалять запись из БД? Хотел сделать промежуточную таблицу для того что бы очищать ее каждый месяц (например) автоматически от всех записей, но спасибо за ответ/совет.

Comment: Почему вручную? Критерия удаления по значению статуса и дате создания заказа будет достаточно.